# Same databinding layout in different fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, data-binding

I got question for implementing same data binding layout in 2 fragment.
Example :
fragment_example.xml it will use by ExampleBasicToolbarFragment and ExampleToolbarImageFragment. in each fragment have onclick function.
How to achieve that?

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="toolbarFragment"
            type="example.toolbar.ExampleBasicToolbarFragment" />

        <variable
            name="imageToolbarfragment"
            type="example.toolbar.ExampleToolbarImageFragment" />
    </data>

    <id.co.cicil.libs.core.view.viewstate.ViewState
        style="@style/Layout.Match"
        android:id="@+id/viewState">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear"
            style="@style/Layout.Match"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                style="@style/TextContent.Normal"
                android:text="INI FRAGMENT"/>
            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/btnSnackbar"
                style="@style/Button.Orange"
                android:text="coba snackbar"
                app:safeOnClick="@{**HOW I PASS MY FUNCTION TO THIS??**}"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </id.co.cicil.libs.core.view.viewstate.ViewState>
</layout>
```

Comment: whats the safeOnClick ?

Comment: Do you want to use a single inflated layout instance in both fragments? If yes - avoid that. Each fragment must control its own view. Again, if yes - why do you need such implementation?

Comment: @ShaluTD it is my custom bindingadater

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu so i have 2 fragment that inflate this `fragment_example.xm`l, and have 1 button to display toast. without databinding i can achieve that without have multiple layout xml. but i'm trying to achieve that with databinding, but i got stucks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use abstraction principle if you need the ability to generalize several classes by extending an interface or abstract class.

```
    <data>
        <variable
            name="customInterface"
            type="example.toolbar.CustomInterface" />
    </data>

    ...

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/btnSnackbar"
                style="@style/Button.Orange"
                android:text="coba snackbar"
                app:safeOnClick="@{() -> customInterface.performClick()}"/>
```

This interface will force extending classes to implement certain behaviour (certain methods). An example:

```
package example.toolbar

interface CustomInterface {
    void performOnClick();
}
```

Both of your fragments now can implement this interface. You will be able to pass the interface instance into view binding instance. An example:

```
class ExampleBasicToolbarFragment extends Fragment, CustomInterface {
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // create view binding instance
        viewBinding.customInterface = this
    }

    @Override
    void performOnClick() {
        ...
    }
}
```

```
class ExampleToolbarImageFragment extends Fragment, CustomInterface {
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // create view binding instance
        viewBinding.customInterface = this
    }

    @Override
    void performOnClick() {
        ...
    }
}
```